# TinyMCE strips off br tags in p tag

Tags: tinymce

Here is the config I am using in `tinymce.init` function:

```
forced_root_block: 'p'
valid_elements : '+a[id|rel|rev|charset|hreflang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title],strong/b,-em,i,strike,u,script,p[class|id|dir|align|style],ol,ul,li,br'
```

But the *tinyMCE* is stripping of `<br>`'s when we hit enter key.
Something like this:

```
    <p><br/></p>
```

is getting sent as

```
    <p></p>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening
I am using **tinyMCE version 3.5.4.1**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if br elements are registered as valid_children of paragraphs. Default they should be, but you never know...

Comment: Also I didnot add any setting for valid_children so it is the default configuration from tinyMCE

Comment: It didn't work the way I expected it was not removing the br in the paragraphs that I have not added a line break

Comment: I think it is right behavior as I see it is happening here also http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php but only difference is when I use save button it replaces br with &nbsp;

Comment: What would make this an answer is if you specified what to put inside `valid_elements` that denotes the br element to be a child of p

Comment: Fwiw, the way to indicate that in your config is `valid_children: '+p[br]'`

Answer (score 4):

In your settings:

```
'remove_trailing_brs': false
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the valid_elements setting in init function p tag needs to have # before as specified here
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

Answer (score 0):

In default settings,

```
Shift + Enter key
```