# disable add br tag when get content tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a problem like this:

I am using TinyMCE v6. whenever I am using:

```
tinymce.get("html").getContent()
```

It always adds a `<br>` tag after a line break.

So can someone help me disable the auto add `<br>` tag after line break?

I have tried:

```
forced_root_block: false,
force_br_newlines: false,
force_p_newlines: false,
```

But it does not work in v6.

HERE IS MY CODE

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#html',
    plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image media code link lists searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount',
    imagetools_cors_hosts: ['picsum.photos'],
    menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough highlight custom | link image media code ruby table mergetags | align lineheight | tinycomments | numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap removeformat',
    toolbar_sticky: true,
    // toolbar_mode: 'floating',
    toolbar_mode: 'wrap',
    autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
    paste_data_images: true,
    autosave_interval: '30s',
    autosave_retention: '2m',
    height: 800,
    statusbar: false,
    forced_root_block: false,
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    extended_valid_elements: 'script[language|type|src]',
    content_css: ['/dist/css/adminlte.min.css'],
    content_css_cors: true,
    importcss_append: true,
    convert_urls: false
});
```

Really sorry for my bad English!!!

disable auto add `<br>` tag after linebreak in TinyMCE v6

Comment: use `'remove_trailing_brs': false` and check. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985200/tinymce-strips-off-br-tags-in-p-tag

Comment: or try : `apply_source_formatting: false, trim_span_elements: false`

Answer (score 0):

Set the newline behavior option to “block” to prevent any new line breaks from appearing in the editor when presssing the enter key:
you can use this option.[image]
**newline_behavior: 'block',**

for more help check this documentation help page.
https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/remove-line-breaks/